# Get ID of the object saved with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Here is my scenario:
I have three models `Subscriber, Subscription, Plan`, with `has_many :through` relationship 
between Subscriber and Plans.
A subscriber can have multiple plans with one active plan. Whenever a subscriber selects a plan I save it using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscriptions`. I get one plan from the form. 
Now my problem is I want to get the ID of the record created in subscriptions table.

Currently I am retrieving it by finding all subscriptions for the subscriber ordered descending on date created and taking first from the resultset. 
Is there any direct method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have this in controller:

```
 @subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:id])
 @subscriber.update_attributes(params[:subscriber])
```

then you can find last subscription id with:

```
 @subscriber.subscriptions.order("created_at DESC").first.id
```

Comment: I am already on using this solution in my current code. Sorry for not mentioning about it in the question. I have updated it now.

Answer (score -1):

@subscriber.subscriptions.last

is a cheaper solution.
otherwise you could write a custom method in your model.

Comment: -1. If you don't specify order, `.last` can give you different record depending on database. In mysql it is not always last created record.